# variable javascrip a php

Tags: php, javascript

quiero la variable "VALOR" pasarla a PHP

```
$('input[type=radio][name=registro]').change(function() {
 var valor = this.value;
});
```

es que lo quiero extraer en php para hacer un llamado a la base de datos ya que el dato que se extrae es un ID de una tabla

he intentando pero no me resulta la consulta seria en la misma pagina

Comment: Suena a que vas a estar usando ajax... o alguno de sus wrappers.

Comment: como hago para hacer ese cambio

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando ajax puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera;

```
$('input[type=radio][name=registro]').change(function() {
 var valor = $(this).val();
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append("valor",valor);
$.ajax({
url: "aqui pones la ruta del archivo php",
method: "POST",
data : datos,
cache: false,
contentType: false, 
success: function(respuesta) {
}
});
```

Luego de aquí en el archivo que colocaste en url recibes la variable así:

```
$VALOR = $_POST["valor"];
```

Ten en cuenta que debes incluir en el archivo donde está el input de tipo radio a jquery.
Disculpa si me comi alguna coma o algo es que lo escribi de mi telefono